# jQuery events not firing consistently

Tags: jquery, css, animation, z-index

I'm attempting to do something fairly simple. I want to slide a menu out from behind an image and have it fade in and out while transitioning.

So, default the menu's z-index is set to -1 and the image is set to 1.

When you mouseover the table I animate the slide and have a timeout function change the z-index of the menu to 2. When you mouseleave of the table, I set the z-index back to -1 and animate the transition back behind the image.

This should work, and it does on occasion. I am noticing, especially if I set mouseover to hover, that sometimes the mouseover\hover function fires after mouseleave fires when the mouse is nowhere near the table it's set to.

So what winds up happening is that sometimes the z-index doesn't get changed properly and you can see the menu appears in front of the image while it is transitioning. Sometimes it still works fine. You'd think it would work the same way each time, for better or worse.

I've tried different methods. I'm using the timeout because it was difficult to keep two non-queued animations running while having a function run when the latter animation completes.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#headerTable").mouseover(function(){

    $("#movableMenu")
    .animate({top: "0px"}, {duration: 750, queue:false})
    .animate({opacity: "1"}, {duration: 1500, queue:false});
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Out: " + $("#movableMenu").css('z-index'));
        $("#movableMenu").css('z-index', 2);
        console.log("Out: " + $("#movableMenu").css('z-index'));
    }, 1500);


});

$("#headerTable").mouseleave(function() {
    console.log("In: " + $("#movableMenu").css('z-index'));
    $("#movableMenu").css('z-index', -1);
    $("#movableMenu")
    .animate({top: "-55px"}, {duration: 750, queue:false})
    .animate({opacity: "0"}, {duration: 1500, queue:false});
    console.log("In: " + $("#movableMenu").css('z-index'));
});

$(".menuItem").hover(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'teal');
    $(this).css('font-size', '18');
    $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
});
$(".menuItem").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'black');
    $(this).css('font-size', '16');
    $(this).css('font-weight', 'normal');
});

});


</script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="headerTable" align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<td><img width="600px" height="225px" src="images/heading2.png" style="z-index:2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="movableMenu" style="width:100%; height:50px; position:relative; top:-55px; z-index:-1; opacity:0">
<span class="menuItem">Home</span><span class="menuItem">Bio</span><span class="menuItem">Media</span><span class="menuItem">Scores</span><span class="menuItem">Lessons</span><span class="menuItem">Repertoire</span><span class="menuItem">Contact</span><span class="menuItem">Links</span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle with this? Just from first looking at your code, you are using a setTimeout, but I think you would want to use the complete function instead of having 2 separate timers. There is also a .stop() you can call in case you mouseover then mouseout before the original animation ends

Comment: Why you don't use CSS transitions for this?

Comment: A couple of thoughts. You will have to add `position: relative` to your image to truly apply a different z-index from the default. Also, instead of changing the z-index attribute, I would recommend altering the `translateZ` property via `translate3d`. You can check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302395/animate-translate3d-with-jquery

Comment: Here is the fiddle, as requested: https://jsfiddle.net/4tuwbyvn/

Comment: @Imgonzalves I haven't used CSS transitions before. A brief look at them, it looks like I can get it to work in relation to itself, can I get it to work in relation to something else? I have to mouse over the image to tell it to move the menu. If it was a matter of hovering over the menu to tell the menu to change, that would be easy.

Comment: @KevinF I tried using a complete function, but I couldn't get it to work with the double non-queued animation.

Comment: @AlexWright I am not changing the z-index of the image, I'm changing the   z-index of the menu. The menu is set with the proper z-index by default, as is the image. I will look into translateZ

Comment: Seeing your fiddle, it works fine for me.

Comment: @divy3993 Are you saying that you can't see the menu on top of the google image? Yes, the animation *works* as in it moves down, but it should be *behind* the google image and never on top.

Comment: @MarcelMarino if you find this fiddle helpful, then tell me, i would explain it. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4tuwbyvn/4/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS transitions are the best there is right now to animate elements on the web. You should give it a try. I create a fiddle based on yours, only with CSS, no JavaScript required. And not too much CSS neither.

**CSS:**

```
.menuItem {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 8px;
    height:200px;
    vertical-align:top;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.menuItem:hover {
    color: teal;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#movableMenu{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    top: -55px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s; /* You can change the speed */
}

#headerTable:hover #movableMenu{
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Maybe need some adjustments, but works.

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/4tuwbyvn/3/

You can learn more about CSS transitions [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Transiciones_de_CSS).

Comment: @Imgonzalves I appreciate the information; I was definitely interested in learning about CSS animation. The issue with your fiddle is that the menu is still visible on top of the image. That was the issue I was having with the z-index.

Answer (score 0):

User event.preventDfault() and/or event.stopPropagation() in your javasript events.