# Jquery chaining with css method is ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I was playing with jquery and i came to a problem.

i want to animate a box when its container is hovered such that each time the container is hovered , box (initial state 1) should be reset to a position (say state 2) then animate to desired position (say state 3).

> HTML

```
<div id="box-container">
    <div id="box"></div>  
</div>
```

> CSS

```
#box-container {
    padding : 10px;
    border : 1px solid #f00;
}

#box {
    display: inline-block;
    background : #fff;
    padding:50px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    transform : translateX(150px);
}
```

> JS

```
$("#box-container").hover(function(){
    console.log("hover in");
    $("#box").css({
        transform : 'translateX(0px)',
        transition : 'initial'
    }).css({
        transform:'translateX(100px)',
        transition : 'transform 0.5s linear'
    });

},function(){
    console.log("hover out");
});
```

but this method is not working. box is going from `state 1  ->  state 3` directly and get stucked. i found that `css()` can't be queued as `animate()` in jquery

working model 1 => [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/singhiskng/xcren51y/3/)

so i tried to break the chain and tried to add some delay by doing this

```
$("#box").css({
    transform : 'translateX(0px)',
    transition : 'initial'
});

setTimeout(function(){console.log("delay")}, 1000);
var x = 4;
console.log("delay");

$("#box").css({
    transform:'translateX(100px)',
    transition : 'transform 0.5s linear'
});
```

but this dosn't work , so i tried `delay()` which works fine for first time. but on second time box got stucked on left

working model 2 => [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/singhiskng/xcren51y/4/)

at last i tried to log the css value of (transform , padding , transition etc) of box after first change (`state 2`)

```
console.log($("#box").css('transform'));
```

and somehow it is working as i wanted it to work

working model 3 => [JSfiddle correct](https://jsfiddle.net/singhiskng/xcren51y/5/)

> - So i want to know why reading css value gives the desired output
> - what is the good way to achieve this output `state 1 (hover)-> state 2 -> state 3  (hover)-> state 2 -> state 3`

all links are working fine as checked on chrome (latest version).

Comment: Very obvious why the chain approach doesn't work....you override the same properties in second `css()` call. No different in concept  than `a=10; a=100; alert(a)//100`

Comment: @charlietfl yaah you are right , but as you see on state 3 transition is set which is going to delay when going to state 2 next time

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're just married to using transform properties, you could just use jQuery animation to move your elements.

Modified CSS:

```
#box-container {
  padding : 10px;
  border : 1px solid #f00;
  position: relative;
}
#box {
  display: inline-block;
  background : #fff;
  padding:50px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
}
```

Modified JavaScript

```
$("#box-container").on('mouseover',function(){

  $('#box').animate({
      left: "0"
    }, 10, function(){

    }).animate({
      left: "100"
    }, 300, function(){

    });

}).on('mouseout',function(){

  $('#box').animate({
    left: "150"
  }, 0, function(){

  });

});
```

Comment: what if i want to do a 3d transform , also i want to know why reading css property make it work

Comment: Reading the CSS properties does work, but chaining chaining `css()` is not the same thing as sequential animation. You're getting exactly the expected output using chaining - you're applying one CSS property, then immediately changing it to something different - you'll never see that transition because it's not applying them both in a series of commands.

Basically chaining will do:

`#box{
  translateX(0px);
  transition : 'initial';
  translateX(150px);
  transition : 'transform 0.5s linear';
}`

That will result in only the last two properties being applied.

Comment: If you want 3D transforms with jQuery try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302395/animate-translate3d-with-jquery